# Using JQuery Pull items from hidden div to another & Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have a page on my site that allows  users to upload photos to a directory on my server.

These photos  (100x100 thumbnails) are then pulled from that directory and placed in a a `<DIV ID=Content>` which the displays All of the photos from that directory.

Coder here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $.ajax({
        url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
        success: function(data){
            var imageNames = [];
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                // store each image name into array
                imageNames.push($(this).attr("href"));
               });

            var sortedImageNames = imageNames.sort();

            for(var i = sortedImageNames.length; i-- > 0;) {
                    var linkImage = 'user-uploads/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var thumbnailImage = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var item = '<div class="item"> <li> <a class="fancybox" href="' 
                        + linkImage 
                        + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class=dropshadow src="' 
                        + thumbnailImage 
                        + '"></a></li></div>';
                    $(item).appendTo('#content');
                }
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, the photo wall is getting too large and I need to implement an infinite scroll feature that pulls 30 images at a time.

From my research it looks like I have to hide the `<DIV ID=Content>`, and then pull 30 images at at a time to a new `<DIV ID=load30>`. I would like it then to load another 30 once a users reaches 200 pixels from the bottom of the page and continue this till there are no more images  to pull from the hidden `<DIV ID=Content>`

Here is the code I have come up with to try to pull images from `<DIV ID=Content> to <Div ID=Load30>`. I'm having using with this, where as the load30 div is not being populated.

Where is my mistake?

I can't seem to get it to work properly.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).endlessScroll( 

    {
        bottomPixels:200,
        callback: function (p) 
            {

            var load30images = $('#content li:lt(30)');
            $('#load30').append(load30images);      
            }   
    }

    );

});
</script>
```